# Different output when compile from PHP and from console

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I am creating cards with tasks in tex format.
Card sample

```
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Карточка №1
\begin{equation*}\text{Решите уравнение}\space \log_{9}{(4x+5)}=5           \end{equation*} \\ 
\begin{equation*}\text{Решите уравнение}\space \log_{4}{(4x+(-1))}=4 \end{equation*} \\ 
\begin{equation*}Решите\space уравнение\space \log_{2}{(1x^2+(-2))} = \log_{2}{6x} \end{equation*} \\ 
\begin{equation*}\text{Решите уравнение}\space \log_{4}{x} = 5 \end{equation*} \\ 
\begin{equation*}\text{Решите уравнение}\space \log_{7}{x} = 2 \end{equation*} \\ 
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this file via shell_exec in PHP, resulting PDF doesn't have any letters, just formulas. But, if I run 
`/usr/bin/pdflatex -output-directory /var/www/files --interaction batchmode 2016-06-15.00-30-46576031369d029.tex` in console, PDF will contain symbols.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Perhaps your php and shell is not using the same latex installation. Look in their log files. Btw: are you sure utf8x and us should be used and not just utf8?

Comment: @daleif nope, in php I execute same command. Just looked at log files and I think this is the cause `! Font T2A/lmr/m/n/10=larm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.`

Comment: The `www` user (or whatever is used by PHP) has no “personal tree” where storing the TFM files for Cyrillic fonts. When you do it from your personal account, they are written under `~/.texmf`

Comment: @egreg is there any way to bypass it? Switch php user ?

Comment: You have somehow to make the `tfm` available files in the “global” directories.

Comment: Would a solution with XeLaTeX be OK? Doing `sudo` in a PHP script doesn't seem to be the best idea.

Comment: That is not what I mean, the path to latex might be different, thus might end up as different latexs

Comment: Of course it will. As I said `sudo` is a temporary workaround for debugging and to check that problem in inaccessible fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, I finish with this

`$output = system("echo 'pass' | sudo -u user /usr/bin/pdflatex -output-directory /var/www/files --interaction batchmode files/".$name.".tex");`

Comment: That is really bad, you definitely need to figure out why your php user does not see the proper path. Have you examined the paths used when executing the php.

Comment: Can you please put the log files of the two runs up somewhere? It is absolutely impossible to guess what is going on without the log files

Comment: Also, `which -a pdflatex` will help.